# Visualizing a table with geom_tile?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to show the density and correlation of responses to 2 survey questions. The responses to each question are factors 1-5, and I want to make a heatmap of the table of response combinations.

My table looks like this:

```
> table(mydata$v47, mydata$v78)

     1  2  3  4  5
  1  2  0  0  0  0
  2  0  2  2  0  0
  3  5  7  8  3  0
  4 12 11 14  7  1
  5  1  1  2  4  1
```

What fill function would I pass to `geom_tile` to to distinguish popular pairs in the table by frequency?

This code

```
ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = v47, y = v78)) + geom_tile()
```

yields this image

[image: ugly table]

Comment: One way to go would be to reshape your data: `ggplot(data = reshape2::melt(table(mydata$v47, mydata$v78)), aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill=value)) + geom_tile()`. You may want the `fill variable to be a factor.

Comment: @user20650 I think that is THE answer, so you might as well post it as such :p

Comment: `data.frame(table(mydata$v47, mydata$v78))` is same as `melt`

Comment: So it is @Khashaa; please write up an answer

Comment: In the same spirit as Luke's answer the `corrplot` package maight be useful: `corrplot::corrplot(table(mydata$v47, mydata$v78), is.corr=F, method="square")`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a modified version of the former `ggflucation()`, which maps tile color and size to frequency:

```
mydata <- read.table(header = F, text = "
0  1  2  3  4  5
1  2  0  0  0  0
2  0  2  2  0  0
3  5  7  8  3  0
4 12 11 14  7  1
5  1  1  2  4  1")
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
tab <- as.table(t(as.matrix(mydata[-1, -1])) %>% set_colnames(1:5) %>% set_rownames(1:5))

ggfluc <- function(tab) {
  if (is.table(tab)) 
    tab <- as.data.frame(t(tab)) 
  tab <- as.data.frame(tab) 
  oldnames <- names(tab) 
  names(tab) <- c("x", "y", "result") 
  tab <- transform(tab, x = as.factor(x), y = as.factor(y), freq = result) 
  ceiling = max(tab$freq); floor = 0 
  tab <- transform(tab, freq = sqrt(pmin(freq, ceiling)/ceiling), 
                   border = ifelse(is.na(freq), "grey90", ifelse(freq > ceiling, "grey30", "grey50"))) 
  tab[is.na(tab$freq), "freq"] <- 1 
  tab <- subset(tab, freq * ceiling >= floor) 
  nx <- length(levels(tab$x)) 
  ny <- length(levels(tab$y)) 
  p <- ggplot(tab, aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", height = "freq", width = "freq", fill = "result")) + 
    geom_tile(colour = "white")
  p
}
ggfluc(tab)
```

[image]